Kotlin SharedFlow extraBufferCapacity problem
For MutableSharedFlow I specify extraBufferCapacity parameter as Int.MAX_VALUE, two coroutines are executed, in the first I emit values, in the other I collect the flow with a delay. Why are the values ​​that I emit not cached in the extraBufferCapacity? Do I understand correctly that until we collect the flow, the values ​​do not fall into extraBufferCapacity?
    val flow = MutableSharedFlow<String>(
        extraBufferCapacity = Int.MAX_VALUE,
        onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST
    )
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
    scope.launch {
        delay(100)
        flow.collect {
            println("Collected: $it")
        }
    }
    flow.tryEmit("1")
    flow.tryEmit("2")
    flow.tryEmit("3")

If I replace the code with Channel then everything works fine, it seems capacity of the Channel works different:
    val channel = Channel<String>(capacity = Int.MAX_VALUE)
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
    scope.launch {
        delay(100)
        for (value in channel) {
            println("Got: $value")
        }
    }
    channel.trySend("1")
    channel.trySend("2")
    channel.trySend("3")

Output:
Got: 1 Got: 2 Got: 3

Correct, when shared flow has no collectors it's completely idle. Similarly when last collector ends while there are values in the buffer they end up being dropped and "unhandled".

You want to use the replay param.
